# Detecting radio button checked via another javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a javascript function that changes which radio buttons are selected as follows:

```
if ($('#tables').hasClass('radiobuttons')){
    var tables = $('#tables').find('table'),
        rows = tables.find('tr'),
        radios = $('input[type="radio"]');

    rows.live('click', function(){
        var clicked = $(this);
        clicked.find('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', true);
        clicked.parent().find('tr').removeClass('selected');
        clicked.addClass('selected');
    });
}
```

Basically, this is allowing the user to click anywhere on a row in a table, and the corresponding radio button will be selected.

The radio buttons all have an `onchange` event attached to them - except that function does **not** get called when the radio button is selected this way.

```
<input type="radio" onchange="someFunction();" name="myradiobutton" value="123">
```

How can I detect that the value has changed other than with the onchange event?

Comment: The last two sentences of your question have me scratching my head.

Comment: He's saying the radio button has an onchange event that is not triggered when his javascript sets the checked attribute of the radio button manually. I agree that the phrasing gave me pause.

Comment: Edited in an attempt to be more clear. @jatrim got it exactly right as to what I'm trying (and failing) to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the attribute on the radio button, try triggering a click event instead.

`clicked.find('input[type=radio]').trigger("click");`

Alternatively, you might try binding your click event handler to the row the user clicks on, instead of (or in addition to) the actual radio button.

Comment: That creates an infinite loop, as the function described above gets called implicitly on the radio buttons' click event.

Comment: That seems like a mistake. Do you need to call this function on both row click and button click? If you do, i suppose you could try binding to a custom event instead. Set your onchange handler to throw it, and throw the same event from this function. Then bind whatever you currently have bound to onchange to this new event. http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2010/02/21/jquery-custom-element-and-global-events.aspx  (And yes, that does seem like a lot of work for something that should be simple.)

Comment: Yes - this function basically checks to perform some validation. It doesn't matter how it is selected - if the state changes, the validation must be done.

Comment: Would it not make sense to trigger the change event instead?

Comment: In my experience, triggering "change" doesn't always seem to work as you'd expect. But you're right, I think it would make sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for target element which has raised the event and decide accordingly. You can get the target element using event object which is the first argument in the event handler.

```
rows.live('click', function(e){
    if($(e.target).is(':radio'){
        //radio button clicked
    }
});
```